# Riemann surfaces with Riemann Roch theorem, linear fiber over an elliptic curve

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, fiber-bundles

Let $g:\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C^*}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C^*}$ defined by $g(z,w)=(w^n z,\alpha z)$ where $0<|\alpha|<1$. Let $G$ be the cyclic group spanned by $g$ and $A$ the group spanned by $w\mapsto \alpha w$. I have to show,by considering a quotient, that we obtain a linear fiber over an elliptic curve (i.e. a torus).
I have no idea how to begin with that question.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: For starters, do you know how to describe the quotient of $\mathbf{C}^{*}$ by the mapping $w \mapsto \alpha w$? (Assuming there's a typo in the second coordinate of $g$....)

Comment: @user86418 I think there is no typo. i read it again. For the quotient, i identify two points (both not 0) that have the same image by $w \mapsto \alpha w$ ?

Comment: The thing is, if $g(z, w) = (w^{n}z, \alpha w)$, then the stated quotient is indeed (the total space of) a line bundle of degree $n$ over an elliptic curve. As written, $g(0, w) = (0, 0)$ for all $w$, and the quotient doesn't look like a manifold...? :) Anyway, the suggestion is to start by focusing on the second component, and to think about the quotient of the non-zero complex numbers by the cyclic group generated by multiplication by $\alpha$.

Comment: @user86418 I see. So what do you propose for a good definition of g ? If i consider the quotient $\mathbb C ^{*} /{w\mapsto \alpha w}$ what can i say about the elliptic curve and the fiber over it ?

Comment: I hope my indirection hasn't caused confusion. In your question, the second component of $g$ is "$\alpha z$"; it should be "$\alpha w$", right...? :)

Comment: @user86418  Everything you will say will help me to understand so do not worry! In my course it is written as $\alpha z$...So let it try with your suggestion...What can i say about the elliptic curve and the fibers ?

Comment: Fix $\alpha$ with $0 < |\alpha| < 1$, and consider $w \mapsto \alpha w$ as a map of $\mathbf{C}^{*}$. (If it helps, start with $\alpha = 1/2$.) What geometric effect does this mapping have on points? On circles centered at the origin? What does a fundamental domain $D$ look like? What happens when you make the indicated boundary identifications on $D$? Next, $g$ defines a properly discontinuous $(\mathbf{Z}, +)$-action on $\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{C}^{*}$, and the effect on fibres (the first coordinate) is linear, so the quotient becomes a line bundle trivialized over the interior of $D$.

Comment: @user86418 The map $w\mapsto \alpha w$ is a contraction. A point (it defines a vector) have a smaller lenght and the radius of a circle is smaller...Am i right ? I have some difficulty to see the fundamental domain $D$.

Comment: Did the question arise in a course you're taking, and if so, what related material have you seen? On a tangent, have you seen a torus presented as a parallelogram with opposite sides identified? (That's not quite what's going on here, but the picture may help anyway.) Also, Lenstra and DeSmit's [analysis of Escher's _Print Gallery_](http://escherdroste.math.leidenuniv.nl/), particularly Figure 4 and the section on elliptic curves in the [accompanying article](http://www.ams.org/notices/200304/fea-escher.pdf) from the _AMS Notices_ should be helpful.

Comment: @user86418 Yes it is in a course ...I have seen sheaf theory, Riemann surfaces, Riemann-Roch theorem...Yes i have seen this picture of a torus. Thank you for the references. By the way, what do you mean by $(\mathbb Z,+)$-action ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}$Here's a fairly detailed sketch of the underlying framework, together with hints for applying the machinery to your situation.

---

**Generalities**: Let $X$ be a connected holomorphic manifold, $\phi:X \to X$ a biholomorphism, and $A$ the cyclic group generated by $\phi$. To get a manifold quotient, we'll assume $A$ acts [*properly discontinuously*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properly_discontinuous_action), i.e., each point $w$ in $X$ has a neighborhood $U$ whose images under $A$ are pairwise disjoint.

The set of $A$-orbits is the *quotient space* $Y = X/A$. There is a natural map $\pi:X \to Y$ defined by $\pi(w) = [w]$, the orbit of $w$ under $A$. If $U$ is a neighborhood of $w$ whose images under $A$ are disjoint, then the image of $U$ in $Y$ is a neighborhood of $[w]$ in the quotient topology, and it's straightforward to check that $Y$ is a holomorphic manifold and $\pi$ is a covering map with [deck transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Deck_transformation) group $A$.

A [*fundamental domain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain) for the action of $A$ is a region $D$ in $X$ such that $\phi(D) \cap D = \emptyset$ and the images of the closure $\overline{D}$ under $A$ cover $X$. We may think of $Y$ as obtained from $\overline{D}$ by "gluing" boundary points identified by $\phi$.

Next, let $p:L \to X$ be a holomorphic line bundle over $X$, and assume we are given a biholomorphism $g:L \to L$ of the total space that maps the fibre $L_{w}$ over $w$ by a *linear* transformation (i.e., via multiplication by a non-zero scalar) to $L_{\phi(w)}$. Let $G$ denote the group of biholomorphisms of $L$ generated by $g$. In this situation, there is an induced line bundle over $Y$ with total space $L/G$. (If $U$ is a trivializing neighborhood for $L$ whose images under $A$ are pairwise disjoint, then the image of $U$ in $Y$ is a trivializing neighborhood for $L/G$, since the quotient map restricted to $U$ is a biholomorphism. In writing up a solution, you'll probably want/need to flesh out the details.)

---

**Particulars**: Fix a complex number $\alpha$ with $0 < |\alpha| < 1$ and an integer $n$. Let $X = \Cpx^{*}$, $\phi(w) = \alpha w$, and $A$ the infinite cyclic group of biholomorphisms generated by $\phi$. (The "$(\mathbf{Z}, +)$-action" in my comment merely referred to an action by an infinite cyclic group.)

We first seek a fundamental domain for the action of $A$.

One natural approach is to observe that circles centered at $0$ map to circles centered at $0$ under $\phi$ (why?). We might therefore seek a fundamental domain $D$ consisting of a union of circles. (Suggestion: Look at images of the unit circle under $\phi$, and try to find a region $D$ bounded by such circles so that the images of $\overline{D}$ cover all of $\Cpx^{*}$. Then investigate how $\phi$ identifies boundary points of $\overline{D}$, with the aim of convincing yourself the quotient space is a torus.)

Now let $L = \Cpx \times \Cpx^{*}$ be the trivial line bundle over $X$ via $p(z, w) = w$.

The mapping $g(z, w) = (w^{n}z, \alpha w)$ is a biholomorphism of the total space of $L$ that covers $\phi$ and is linear on fibres. (All three claims require a bit of justification, but should be easy.) For the general reasons outlined above, the quotient of $\Cpx \times \Cpx^{*}$ by the infinite cyclic group $G$ generated by $g$ is a holomorphic line bundle over the torus $\Cpx^{*}/A$.

Incidentally, identifying $(z, w)$ with $(w^{n}z, \alpha w)$ "twists" the quotient line bundle: The fibre coordinate $z$ over the unit circle $\{|w| = 1\}$ in the quotient $\Cpx^{*}/A$ gets identified with the fibre coordinate $w^{n}z$ over the (same) circle $\{|w| = |\alpha|\}$. Roughly, the fibre coordinate of $L/G$ with respect to one trivialization "rotates" $n$ times with respect to a second trivialization.

Comment: Very useful answer! Is your $G$ my $A$ defined in the problem? I am working on your answer, please give me a little time to understand the last part (after the definition of a fundamental domain).

Comment: @Far: Oops, yes; fixed.

Comment: I understand better now. The images of the unit circle get smaller and smaller. But i am stuck here. How can i get a region D bounded by such circles? I think your $L/G$ is the linear bundle $L$ of my problem, isn't it?

Comment: Two concentric circles in the plane bound a region, right...? :) (Note that $\Cpx^{*}$ isn't simply-connected, so the covering of the torus $\Cpx^{*}/A$ is not the standard parallelogram picture, but instead is "already partily glued".)

Comment: Do you mean the punctured disk of radius 1 around the point 0 (that is an annulus ann(z=0,r=0,R=1) )?

Comment: Not quite; the punctured annulus contains infinitely many points that get identified by $A$. (All integer powers of $\alpha$ are identified with $1$, for instance.) But if you take two "consecutive" circles, do any points in the interior of the annulus get identified? Does every non-zero number get identified with some point in the annulus?

Comment: No, i agree with you. The orbit of a complex z (not 0) consists of points that are on a segment which passes through the origin (without it) and that point z. So i have to pick one point in each orbit so that they form a domain $D$ such that $\phi(D)\cap D=\emptyset $...but i do not see how to chose such a domain.

Comment: Just checking your picture of "segments": The orbits of $A$ are _discrete_, consisting of countably many points on a logarithmic spiral. For instance, if $\alpha = 1/2$, the orbit of $1$ is the set $\{\dots, 1/8, 1/4, 1/2, 1, 2, 4, 8, \dots\}$ of powers of $1/2$. So, if you look at the annulus $1/2 < |w| < 1$....

Comment: Ok i see now. But why do we need a fundamental domain for our action ?

Comment: I have to prove, in the same problem, that every meromorphic function that verifies $\forall w \in \mathbb {C}^*$, $f(\alpha w)=w^n f(w)$ defines a meromorphic section of the bundle $L$. So a section $\sigma$ is from $\mathbb{C}^*$ to L:=$C\times C^*$/G. I will try tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: I think i have to prove that $\sigma : \mathbb{C}^*/A \mapsto L $ is meromorphic. So i can write that $\sigma(z+a)=\sigma(z)$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}^*$ and $a\in D$. But i am stuck here. Have you any idea ?

Comment: Recall that $g$ identifies $(z, w)$ and $g(z, w) = (w^{n}z, \alpha w) = (z', w')$. A meromorphic section of the quotient, lifted to $\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{C}^{*}$, has the form $z = f(w)$ with $f$ meromorphic if and only if the graph of $f$ is $g$-invariant, if and only if $z' = f(w')$, .... :)

Comment: I see...it is like the notion of equivariant function. I have an example of such a function : $f(z,w)=z.\prod_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}(\frac{w}{w-\alpha^{k}\zeta})^n$ for all $\zeta$,$n$. Am i right ?

Comment: i have some difficulty to prove that $(z,w)\mapsto f(z,w)$ is a section of $L$ over $E$. Do i have to prove that $f(z,\alpha w)=w^n f(z,w)$ ? And how i can deduce the degree of $L$ ?

Comment: I hate to say it, but it's probably best to post a separate question about meromorphic sections (linking back to this question); Math.SE is designed to accumulate searchable answers to well-delimited questions with all useful information contained in the question and answers, and our discussion in these comments contains non-trivial additional material.

Comment: Ok, i will follow your advice. Thank you, i have learned a lot with you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280158/riemann-roch-meromorphic-section-on-a-line-bundle