# Riemann Roch Meromorphic section on a line bundle.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, vector-bundles, complex-manifolds, holomorphic-bundles

Let $g:\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C^*}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C^*}$ defined by $g(z,w)=(w^n z,\alpha w)$ where $0<|\alpha|<1$. Let $G$ be the cyclic group spanned by $g$ and $A$ the group spanned by $w\mapsto \alpha w$.

I have the following result : Any meromorphic map with the condition $\forall w\in \mathbb C^*,f(\alpha w)=w^n f(w)$ defines a meromoprhic section on the bundle $L:=\mathbb C \times\mathbb C^*/G$ (L is a bundle over the elliptic curve $E:=\mathbb C^*/A$).

1) I have to verify that the function $f$ defined by : 
$f(z,w)=z.\prod_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}(\frac{w}{w-\alpha^{k}\zeta})^n,    \forall \zeta$ fixed in $\mathbb C$,$\forall n$
is a section of $L$ over $E$. 
Do i have to check that $f(z,\alpha w)=w^n f(z,w)$? Or use the fact that the points $(z,w)$ and $g(z,w)$ are identified in $L$ ? I have some difficulties here.

2) After, how can i deduce the degree of $L$?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible the section of $L$ is induced by the graph of the meromorphic function
$$
\phi(w) = \prod_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{w}{w - \alpha^{k}\zeta}\right)^{n}
$$
rather than somehow being defined by $f(z, w) = z\phi(w)$?

Comment: @user86418 In the exercise, the expression of $f$ is given by the one i have  written above...

Comment: I see.... The thing is, the "equivariant function condition" $f(\alpha w) = w^{n} f(w)$ makes sense as a defining condition for a section (as we discussed in your first question), but I'm not sure how to interpret a function of two variables as defining a section. If your instructor meant $f(w) = \phi(w)$ with $\phi$ as in my comment, then the condition to check is: If $(z', w') := g(z, w) = (w^{n}z, \alpha w)$ and $z = f(w)$, then $z' = w^{n} f(w')$. For $f$ as written, you do have $f(g(z, w)) = w^{n} f(z, w)$, but then $f$ seems to define a section with $L$ as _base space_.

Comment: @user86418 Ok i am asking to my instructor...but how do you prove, if we use your definition, that $\phi(\alpha w)=w^{n}\phi(w)$ ? Because of the infinit product, i am not able to write it.

Comment: @user86418 Ok, once again, you are right! You can fix the $z$ variable. The infinite product has to converge so, i think, it is, in fact, a finite product. But how to see it ?

Comment: To me it looks like the infinite product is $0$ for all $w$.

Comment: @user86418 But how do you see that $f(g(z,w))=w^n f(z,w)$ ?

Comment: @Far: Straight substitution and algebra show $\phi(\alpha w) = \phi(w)$. (Actually, as mercio notes, the product is $0$. Presumably your instructor meant some non-trivial product of the same formal structure, for which replacing $w$ by $\alpha w$ and canceling $\alpha/\alpha$ "shifts" the factors in the product.) Now if you write $(z', w') = g(z, w) = (w^{n}z, \alpha w)$, you only need to show $f(z', w') = w^{n} f(z, w)$, which is immediate....

Comment: @user86418 How can you see that $\phi(w)$ is $0$ for all $w$? I tried to show that it converges to $0$ by using the facts that $0<|\alpha|<1$ and $|\alpha|<|w|<1$ but it seems to be non trivial...

Comment: @user86418 if you have time, can you have a look at : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281619/sheaf-%C3%A9tal%C3%A9-space-with-riemann-surfaces Thank you.

Comment: Re: $\phi(z) = 0$ if $\zeta \neq 0$, the factors with $k \ll 0$ have magnitude on the order of $1/|\alpha^{k} \zeta| \to 0$, while factors with $k \gg 0$ have magnitude on the order of $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to skip the nonsensical first question and answer the second.

Consider a nonzero meromorphic global section $f$ (i.e. a meromorphic function $f : \Bbb C^* \to \Bbb P^1(\Bbb C)$ such that $f(\alpha.w) = w^nf(w)$).

We pick a fundamental domain $\Omega$ for $\Bbb C^*/A$, for example the region $|\alpha| < |w| < 1$. Then the degree of $f$ is $\deg(f) = \frac 1 {2i\pi} \int_{\partial  \Omega} \frac {f'(w)}{f (w)}dw$ .

Since the boundary of $\Omega$ is two circles, $2i\pi \deg(f) = \int_{|w|=1} \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw - \int_{|w|=|\alpha|} \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw $, where each circle is oriented in the standard way.

Using a change of variables, $\int_{|w|=|\alpha|} \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw = \int_{|w|=1} \frac{f'(\alpha w)}{f(\alpha w)}d(\alpha w) = \int_{|w|=1} \frac{\alpha f'(\alpha w)}{f(\alpha w)}dw$.

Now, since $f(\alpha w) = w^n f(w)$ we have $\alpha f'(\alpha w) = nw^{n-1}f(w) + w^nf'(w)$.

Hence  $\int_{|w|=|\alpha|} \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}dw = \int_{|w|=1}( \frac nw + \frac {f'(w)}{f(w)}) dw$.

we get $2i\pi \deg(f) = - \int_{|w|=1} \frac nw dw = -2i\pi n$, and so $\deg(f) = \deg(L) = -n$.

In particular, this tells us that $f$ has to have at least $n$ poles in $\Omega$, and so there is no holomorphic global section of $L$

Comment: Thank you it is very clear. So it means that dimension of $H^0 (E,\mathcal{O}(L))$, that is the space of holomorphic sections of $L$, is 0 ? And what about the dimension of $H^1 (E,\mathcal{O}(L))$ ?

Comment: If i use the formula : $\chi(L)=deg(L)+(1-g)=h^0 (L) - h^1 (L)$ it gives me $h^1 (L) = n$ with $g=1$. Am i right ?

Comment: yes, that looks right. I was incidentally looking at the same formula.

Comment: This formula is valid when the riemann surface (the base here $E$) is compact and connected. Thank you.

Comment: If you have time, can you look at : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281619/sheaf-%C3%A9tal%C3%A9-space-with-riemann-surfaces . Thank you.