# Sheaf, étalé space with Riemann surfaces.

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology, etale-cohomology

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be an holomorphic map betwen two Riemann surfaces and let:

$\Gamma:=${ $(x,y)\in X\times Y|y=f(x)$ } $\subset X\times Y$ be the graph of $f$.
I have to show that $(\Gamma,proj_{|\Gamma},X) $, where $proj_{|X}:X\times Y\rightarrow X$ is the first projection, is an étalé space which is isomorphic to $X$.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: I have to prove that $proj_{|\Gamma}$ is a local homeomorphism. So if $U$ is a neighborhood of a point in $\Gamma$ then $proj_{|\Gamma} (U)$ is open in $X$ and $proj|_{U}:U\rightarrow p(U)$ is a homeomorphism. How can i show this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**: Let $i_{X}$ denote the identity map on $X$. The map $i_{X} \times f:X \to X \times Y$ is a holomorphic bijection to $\Gamma$, and projection $\operatorname{proj}_{X}:X \times Y \to X$ on the first factor is a holomorphic map whose restriction to $\Gamma$ is the inverse of $i_{X} \times f$.

Comment: So i can use the holomorphic Inverse function theorem... With $d_x (i_X \times f)=(i_X,d_x f )$ and this last is non zero everywhere?

Comment: Yes (modulo your precise statement of the inverse function theorem): The differential of $i_{X} \times f$ obviously has maximal rank because $i_{X}$ does. :)

Comment: Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $U$ and $p\in U$
so that $f'(p) \neq 0$ : Then there exists an open neighborhood $V$
of $p$ so that $f : V\rightarrow f(V)$) is biholomorphic. So here $f$ is your $i_X \times f$, $U$ is an open set in $X$ and $f(V)$ an open set in $\Gamma$...